# Vue js - Add text and dropdown box inside the html content editable box

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using vue js. I am trying add **text and dropdown box** inside the html editable div.

I want to add the dropdown box using a button. This dropdown can be added to any positoin of the text. Like where I put my cursor.

Now, it's almost working but I can not find an issue.

When I type and add multiple dropdown and then press the **"Get Data Model"** button, it's always showing me incorrect selected option from the dropdown. I mean its always showing me the first option.

Using this **Get Data Model** button I am trying the get all the text + selection options.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="content-editable" contenteditable="true" @input="onInput" ref="contentEditable"></div>
    <button @click="addDropdown">Add Dropdown</button>
    <button @click="getDataModel">Get Data Model</button>
    <div>{{ dataModel }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: '',
      dropdowns: [],
      dropdownOptions: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
      dataModel: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      this.content = event.target.innerHTML.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g, '');
    },
    addDropdown() {
      const dropdown = {
        selectedOption: this.dropdownOptions[0],
      };
      this.dropdowns.push(dropdown);
      const editableDiv = this.$refs.contentEditable;
      const dropdownSelect = document.createElement('select');
      dropdownSelect.style.width = '100px';

      this.dropdownOptions.forEach((option) => {
        const dropdownOption = document.createElement('option');
        dropdownOption.value = option;
        dropdownOption.text = option;
        dropdownSelect.appendChild(dropdownOption);
      });

      editableDiv.appendChild(dropdownSelect);
    },
    getDataModel() {
      const editableDiv = this.$refs.contentEditable;
      const clonedDiv = editableDiv.cloneNode(true);
      const selectElements = clonedDiv.querySelectorAll('select');

      this.dropdowns.forEach((dropdown, index) => {
        const selectedOption = dropdown.selectedOption;
        const selectedOptionText = Array.from(selectElements[index].options).find((option) => option.value === selectedOption)?.text;

        const selectedOptionTextNode = document.createTextNode(` ${selectedOptionText}`);
        selectElements[index].replaceWith(selectedOptionTextNode);
      });

      this.dataModel = clonedDiv.textContent;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.content-editable {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuejs is data-driven, MVVM thinks, if you want to create multiple 'input
' tag Please use v-for more reasonable instead of dynamically creating DOM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <style scoped>
        .content-editable {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            min-height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <template>
            <div>
                <button @click="addDropdown">creatSelect</button>
                <div v-for="(dropdown, index) in dropdowns" :key="index">
                    <select v-model="dropdown.selectedValue">
                        <option v-for="option in dropdown.options" :value="option.value" :key="option.value">{{
                            option.label }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button @click="getAllSelectedValues">getValue：</button>
            <div>valueList：{{ allSelectedValues }}</div>
        </template>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            dropdowns: [],

            dropdownOptions: [
                { value: 'option1', label: 'option1' },
                { value: 'option2', label: 'option2' },
                { value: 'option3', label: 'option3' },
                { value: 'option4', label: 'option4' },
            ],
            allSelectedValues: [],
        },
        methods: {
            addDropdown() {
                this.dropdowns.push({
                    selectedValue: null,
                    options: this.dropdownOptions,
                });
            },
            getAllSelectedValues() {
                this.allSelectedValues = this.dropdowns.map((dropdown) => dropdown.selectedValue);
            },
        },

    })


</script>
```

希望能帮到你！